# Overwrite a already overwritten template(.phtml) file

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, module

The product listing page is already overwritten by a module from local codepool provided by theme. `[Module name : shopby]`

Inside the active theme in design area, `layout > shopby.xml` i can see this

```
<reference name="product_list">
     <action method="setTemplate">
         <template>sm/shopby/catalog/product/list.phtml</template>
     </action>
</reference>
```

I want to take this file `list.phtml` and make few modifications leaving this file untouched and want to overwrite by another custom module(just to overwrite this file/other technique). Because with this the added modifications will only be applied on active of this module.

Is it possible to overwrite this product listing page as it's already being overwritten ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is what `local.xml` do for you. Create a new file `local.xml` inside the same design package and then add this code.

File : `app\design\frontend\{package}\{theme}\layout\local.xml`

```
<layout>
    <catalog_category_default>
        <reference name="product_list">
             <action method="setTemplate">
                 <template>myupdates/catalog/product/customlist.phtml</template>
             </action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>
    <catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="product_list">
             <action method="setTemplate">
                 <template>myupdates/catalog/product/customlist.phtml</template>
             </action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
</layout>
```

Now create a new template file in the same design package with a directory sturcture `app\design\frontend\{package}\{theme}\template\myupdates/catalog/product/customlist.phtml` and copy paste all content of the `list.phtml` to there and do modifications.

Comment: Thank you this works. But as i have said in the question, how can i toggle between this two layouts ? (i was thinking about like a module and with enabling and disabling, the product list template files will be applied) so how can i enable/disable this ?

Comment: @K.C. If you want to toggle, you need to comment out this section from `local.xml`. Otherwise you need to create a module and add same code in your custom layout xml file. So if your module is active, it will use your custom list phtml file. If your module is disabled, then it will go for theme's list.phtml file.

Comment: @K.C. If the answer helped you to resolve your issue, then you can accept this answer by mark the tick ON thanks

Comment: ya ya, sure. Exactly via custom module.